# What is the preferred way of letting users sort listviews by predefined sort orders?

Tags: android, user-interface, sorting, listview, android-listview

What would you use? Menu? Context menu? Would you rather add the sort order for that particular ListView as an option in your application's Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set up buttons indicating sort orders at the top of the layout each of which corresponded to an OnClickListener that fetched a new cursor and then simply called a

```
adapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
```

on the listview adapter.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the different options, I went with a spinner at the top of the screen. Here is what layout is right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Spinner android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40sp" android:id="@+id/spinner_sort_order ">     
    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">        
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

    <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is empty -->
    <TextView android:text="@string/empty_list_default_value"
        android:id="@+id/txt_empty_list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center">
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```